# Cómo cargar todos los documentos de una colección desde una base de datos echa en Firebase conectada flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Buenas a todos programadores, he estado buscando la manera de cargar todos los documentos, algo así lo que en base de datos relacionales es un selec * from table; y pues he encontrado este código en esta misma plataforma,pero en otro idioma y es el siguiente :

```
getDocumentData ()async {

CollectionReference _cat = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("alumno");
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _cat.get();
    final _docData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
        
}
```

Básicamente lo que tengo que hacer como proyecto es un carrito de compras utilizando flutter y cloud firestore. Considero que necesito saber como cargar todos los productos desde la base de datos a mi aplicación. El código que ven anteriormente es no me marca error, pero tampoco hace algo, lo pongo con un foreach y no sucede nada, trate de ver el tamaño que tenía la lista y pues tampoco, o bueno el tamaño es de cero. Entonces no sé si existe alguien que me diga como le hago o como le hago para obtener los datos de la lista, por favor.
El otro codigo que probe es directamente de la documentación pero tampoco pasa algo

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('alumno')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc['correo']);
        });
    });
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar el esquema de ese documento "productos"?. La documentación normalmente hace referencia a documentos y datos que no tienes, ¿comprobaste que tienes una colección de tipo productos con datos en el panel de Firebase?, suena a que intentas obtener datos de una colección que no tienes o directamente no has creado aún.